# How to modify Finder "Quick Actions: Convert Image" default options?

Tags: finder, automation, monterey

I find Finder's right-click: `Quick Actions`: `Convert Image` to be quite useful for quick conversion of images, but I'd like to change the default for "Image Size" for example from "Small" to "Large" and to turn off "Preserve Metadata".
[image: example]

Where can these defaults be changed?

Comment: You could create your own Quick Action in Shortcuts.app with the parameters that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS 13.4, it's "Actual Size" by default.

[image]

Comment: The question was asking: *"Where can these defaults be changed?"* Are you answering this?